# Sync or manage production dev and uat the right way

Tags: oracle10g, synchronization

I am working on oracle 10.2. I am fairly new.

I have been given project to synchronize parameters & patches for our 3 main databases - production, development and testing, because there is a huge difference between them, parameters and patches wise.

We cannot replicate because the production is in Terabytes. And development and testing are fairly small databases. But my job is to keep them sync on daily basis. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "keep[ing] them [in] sync"?  That phrase normally refers to synchronizing data but it sounds like that is not the case here.  Are you really only interested in keeping initialization parameters and Oracle database patches synchronized?

Comment: the differences between different database environments. Take action to synchronise the databases.
•  User accounts
•  privileges
•  packages
•  tablespaces
•  Database parameters / settings
•  Patches
this is what i have to do.

Comment: and i need some one to point me in the right direction if possible example scripts or queries will b ACE

Answer (score 0):

Use TOAD Database -> Compare -> Schemas (or Single Objects) and apply changes from DEV to UAT and from UAT to PROD, although generating patches in DEV and applying them to UAT and then to PROD would be better.

Comment: well we have called oracle to create a patch for us to do it. cheers guys specially alexs